# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException spark flatMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Related code is as followed:**

```
val cateList = featureData.map{
  case (psid: String, label: String, cate_features: ParArray[String], media_features: String) =>
      val pair_feature = cate_features.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._2, x._1))
      pair_feature
}.flatMap(_.toList)
```

it come with wrong in flatMap, what's wrong? where there exist problem?

**Full error info:**

it mainly post error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. i think there exist somewhere to visit array out of bound. i am not familiar with scala. Any help will welcome. tks.

```
17/01/23 12:23:08 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 29.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 53) on executor 10.39.2.232: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (3) [duplicate 9]
17/01/23 12:23:08 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 29 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job 
17/01/23 12:23:08 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Cancelling stage 0
17/01/23 12:23:08 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Stage 0 was cancelled
17/01/23 12:23:08 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 0 (flatMap at ETL.scala:132) failed in 27.635 s
17/01/23 12:23:08 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: reduce at ETL.scala:205, took 27.763709 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 29 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 29.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 53, 10.39.2.232): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3    at com.sina.adalgo.feature.ETL$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$13.apply(ETL.scala:111)
at com.sina.adalgo.feature.ETL$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$13.apply(ETL.scala:111)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Spark UI error information**

i posted as followed:
[spark ui error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfyrM.png)

Comment: Please post the full error output. Where is the error exactly?

Comment: Why do you think this code is causing the error?  I don't see anything there that would cause it.

Comment: spark ui information is posted, some error are showed. thks

Comment: Can you try not to use `ParArray` and run a test if this fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing further details of the code, I spotted two possible places.

First is the pattern matching for `featureData`. When doing the mapping, you try to match with pattern `(psid: String, label: String, cate_features: ParArray[String], media_features: String)` but failed to handle the patterns do not match the pattern.

Second is the `toList` method. I suppose that's a method from the API. Could you try this one: `flatMap(x => List(x._1,x._2))` - I wrote it on flight, didn't test.

Comment: it's the first pattern, because there existed dirty data. tks